# what is the best way to create an asp.net mvc controller action with lots of variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i have a URL

```
http://www.mysite.com/RunReport
```

and a controller action:

```
    [CompressFilter]
    public ActionResult RunReport(int field1, int field2, int field3, int field4, int field5, int field6, . . .)
```

so to run the query with a filter, you wind of having to do something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/RunReport/0/0/0/0/0/1/0. . . .
```

is there a better way of doing this without such a ugly url and routing?

i want to be able to have persistent URL that maps to specific queries.

Comment: you sure that action shouldn't be a POST? if so, you could use model binding. one parameter - data in form fields.

Comment: @RPM1984 - i would like to avoid having to have a form if possible as i have these links all over the place and (more importantly) i want to have persistent URLs that map to specific queries

Comment: fair enough. in that case im interested to see the answers. i don't think it's possible. a HTTP GET has no body - just the URL and the QS params. maybe you could use a bit/flag kind of thing to reduce the *number* of parameters. either way though, the fields have to go in the URL somehow.

Comment: @RPM1984 - i removed the get as i don't really care if its a get or a post . . .

Comment: out of curiosity, what is this View doing? Just rendering out a specific customer report based on some fields? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a landing page with "Find a Report", with a form, etc then post to this action method and render the view? btw - you could create a route so that the URL would be **http://www.mysite.com/RunReport?fields=0-0-0-0-0-1-0** still ugly, but not *as* ugly, and only 1 qs param as opposed to multi-level folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to have these fields in the Route. You can have them in a query string like so:

RunReport?field3=1

You can then combine them into a POCO class like so

```
public class MyModel
{
    int? Field1 { get; set; }
    int? Field2 { get; set; }
    int? Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

This makes your Fields optional and your Model class can have some smarts in it too, that can determine which report you want to run for example.

And controller action

```
public ActionResult RunReport(MyModel model)
```

This will work with either GET or POST (or whatever other verb you want to use